# Twitter button click crashing app ? Unable to extract the trust manager on okhttp3.internal.Platform$Android

Tags: android, twitter, okhttp, twitter-fabric

issues is with Twitter button, this is working fine with Android 6 Moto G, while on android 5.0.1 Samsung Note 3 it crashes, on Simulator it works fine too,

However my code for Click is,

```
TwitterLoginButton twitterLoginButton = (TwitterLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.button_twitter);
    twitterLoginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
            Log.d(TAG, "twitterLogin:success" + result);

            handleTwitterSession(TwitterAuthProvider.getCredential(
                    result.data.getAuthToken().token,
                    result.data.getAuthToken().secret), false);
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
            Log.w(TAG, "twitterLogin:failure", exception);
        }
    });
    twitterLoginButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Issues it is showing is,

```
java.lang.RuntimeException:Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.my.project/com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.OAuthActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to extract the trust manager on okhttp3.internal.Platform$Android@2e0793c7, sslSocketFactory is class crittercism.android.q
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2693)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to extract the trust manager on okhttp3.internal.Platform$Android@2e0793c7, sslSocketFactory is class crittercism.android.q
                                                                    at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<init>(OkHttpClient.java:187)
                                                                    at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<init>(OkHttpClient.java:60)
                                                                    at okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder.build(OkHttpClient.java:718)
                                                                    at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.internal.oauth.OAuthService.<init>(OAuthService.java:56)
                                                                    at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.internal.oauth.OAuth1aService.<init>(OAuth1aService.java:69)
                                                                    at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.OAuthActivity.onCreate(OAuthActivity.java:69)
                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6283)
                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448) 
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

i searched a lot on google but unable to find any helpful, solution.

Comment: Any solution for the above error

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with Crittercism. If updating that doesn't help you'll need to report the bug to them.